# how to perform arithmetic in pandas, when the columns involved change depending on the row. Summing Columns of Varying Length

Tags: python, pandas, apply

```
# Create a test data set based on the below dictionary
import pandas as pd
import math
import random
num_of_rows = 10000
data = {
    'x1' : [random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) for x in range(num_of_rows)],
    'x2' : [random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) for x in range(num_of_rows)],
    'x3' : [random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) for x in range(num_of_rows)],
    'term': [random.randint(1, 3) for x in range(num_of_rows)]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()
```

| x1 | x2 | x3 | term |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.103324 | 0.304647 | 0.979813 | 3 |
| 0.420082 | 0.416356 | 0.848054 | 2 |
| 0.722017 | 0.888290 | 0.728066 | 3 |
| 0.796869 | 0.535150 | 0.833837 | 2 |
| 0.764554 | 0.244415 | 0.479697 | 1 |

```
%%timeit
# To goal is to sum as month columns as indicated by the term column
def sum_rows(list = [], cnt = 0):
    return sum(list[:int(cnt)])
df['sum'] = df.apply(lambda x: sum_rows([x['x1'], x['x2'], x['x3']], x['term']), axis=1)
df
```

output - 217 ms ± 1.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
%%timeit
#  This appraoch advoids the apply function, but is very confusing to read
df['sum'] = df['x1'] * (df['term'] >= 1) + df['x2'] * (df['term'] >= 2) + df['x3'] * (df['term'] >= 3)
df
```

output - 1.89 ms ± 6.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

The second approach is shown to be over 100 times quicker than using the apply function
Are there alternative approaches to performing the above calculation what would be considered superior?
What if I wanted to multiply the columns (instead of adding), the second approach will not longer give work

Output of sum is :

| x1 | x2 | x3 | term | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.103324 | 0.304647 | 0.979813 | 3 | 1.387784 |
| 0.420082 | 0.416356 | 0.848054 | 2 | 0.836438 |
| 0.722017 | 0.888290 | 0.728066 | 3 | 2.338373 |
| 0.796869 | 0.535150 | 0.833837 | 2 | 1.332019 |
| 0.764554 | 0.244415 | 0.479697 | 1 | 0.764554 |

Comment: Kindly provide the expected output dataframe for multiplication

Comment: I am more interested in what should we reuse instead of apply function, i have edited and added output of sum.

Comment: The output is different from the calculation you shared. How did you get the new values?

Comment: corrected output, as dta is generating randomly, I had attached wrong output.

Comment: Found one solution to use numpy : import numpy as np
df['sum1']=np.where(df.term>=3, df.x1+df.x2+df.x3, np.where(df.term>=2, df.x1+df.x2,df.x1))